# Error when trying to reload data in UITableView in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, option-type, reloaddata

**Still not solved!**

I have been stuck with this problem way too long, so i hope you can help.

I Have two UITableViews side-by-side in one view in Storyboard. Each in a ContainerView to control their positions. 
The idea is, if you touch a row in the first UITableView. The data from that row should be added to the second UITableView.

In TableOne i'm calling the function `addDataToTableView()` in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`.

In Tabletwo `addDataToTableView()` get's the touched element and add it to the testData2 array. This works fine. The `print()` function spits out the right element.

But then on `self.tableTwo.reloadData()` the application crash with this error message:

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

I’m not entirely sure what causes the Error, but i think it’s either that i don’t get the right instance of the class, created by the storyboard or it’s something with optimals.
i tried putting in some ??? and som !!! and i have tried wrapping .reloaddata() ind another thread. but it didn’t help.

This is the entire code.

Hope you can help :)

TableOne

```
class TableOne: UITableViewController {
let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
var tableTwo = TableTwo()
var testData = ["test1","test2", "test3", "test4", "test5", "test6"]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableTwo = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("tableTwoId") as! TableTwo
}

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return testData.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = UITableViewCell()
    cell.textLabel?.text = testData[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    tableTwo.addDataToTableView(testData[indexPath.row])
}
}
```

TableTwo

```
class TableTwo: UITableViewController {
@IBOutlet var tableTwo: UITableView!
var testData2 = ["Test"]

func addDataToTableView(data: AnyObject) {
    testData2.append(data as! String)
    print("This works fine \(testData2[testData2.count-1] )")
    self.tableTwo.reloadData()
}

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return testData2.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = UITableViewCell()
    cell.textLabel?.text = testData2[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}
}
```

Comment: in what line does it crash?

Comment: on "self.tableTwo.reloadData()" it says thread 1 exc_bad_instruction (code=exc_i386_invop subcode=0x0)

Comment: who is calling addDataToTableView? assert reloading happens on main thread only!

Comment: I'm calling addDataToTableView in TableOne - didSelectRowAtIndexPath, i Used this to for threading and ran the reloading on main thread: `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
 // do some task
 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
  // update some UI
 });
});`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send data from One TableViewController either use `prepareForSegue` or `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`.

This line `let cell = UITableViewCell()` you only declare an instance of a UITableViewCell by you never called the method which makes that cell reusable in the queue.

```
            class TableOne: UITableViewController 
            {
                var testData = [String]()

            override func viewDidLoad() 
            {
                super.viewDidLoad()
             testData = ["test1","test2", "test3", "test4", "test5", "test6"]
            }
            override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int 
            {
                return testData.count
            }

            override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell 
            {
                let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CellIdentifier", forIndexPath: indexPath)
                cell.textLabel?.text = testData[indexPath.row]
                return cell
            }
```

**"CellIdentifier"** is the name of the cell identifier from the tableView cell prototype into the storyboard

To send Data the TableView lets say we are using `prepareForSegue` and you must know that When the user selected one cell only that cell information will be sent to your next ViewController.

```
    if segue.identifier == "NAME_OF_THE_SEGUE_IDENTIFIER"
    {
      let destination = segue.destinationViewController as("nameOftheTableView")
      let indexPath = mytableview.indexPathForSelectedRow!
      var dataToTransfer = testData[indexPath.row]
        // let's say you have a string variable into your next ViewContrller called receiver
       destination.receiver = dataToTransfer //<-- from the selectRow we assign that value into our next Controller.
    }
```

So Build up on that to fix your code :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer but i'm not trying to send data from one view to another. My UITableViews are side by side in the same view.  So as far as I'm concerned I should not use prepareForSegue.

Comment: It's the same thing because what you are trying to do is to send data from tableview to another

Comment: What kind of segue should i use when i'm not trying to navigate, but only send data? You say i could use either  `prepareForSegue` or `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`. Did you see that i am using `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` in TableOne? `The print()` in `addDataToTableView()` get the right data when tableOne is touched. Anyway I tried prepareForSegue (maybe not with the right segue) but got same error.

Comment: Here's what i tried:     `override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("dataTranferSegue", sender: indexPath);
    }
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "dataTranferSegue"
        {
            let destination = segue.destinationViewController as! TableTwo
            let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!
            destination.addDataToTableView(testData[indexPath.row]);
        }
    }`